# Multiple instances of Google reCaptcha

Tags: html, recaptcha

I used google reCaptcha for my website and my login and register form are in same page and when I use reCaptcha twice, the second captcha doesn't work.

I used this code for login and register form:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="********"></div>
```

Any body can help me to solve it ?

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the following code I fixed that problem:

form:

```
<div id="captcha"></div>
```

head:

```
var captchaCallback = function() {
    grecaptcha.render('captcha', {
        'sitekey' : ''
    });
};

</script>

<script src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=captchaCallback&render=explicit&hl=en" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Only Answer: You can't.

It's not possible to do that with reCAPTCHA. Only one CAPTCHA is supported in a page at any time. It seems that multiple forms on the same page must share a CAPTCHA, unless you're willing to use a different CAPTCHA.

You can just put login on one page and register on another, because that's all you can do. Or you can [use more JavaScript and load another CAPTCHA after the form is loaded](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/recaptcha/kOYcRJCSDXM).

Comment: this may have been true for v1, but definitly is supported for reCaptcha v2! @amiroperator s solution works!